# Running queries through function is making program slow

Tags: php, mysql, function

I am using n number of queries in my program based on php mysql. To shorten the length I defined a query function:

```
FILE: function.php
function myquery($query){
        $connection  = connect();
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        return $result;
    }
```

and accessing it like on various locations in a same page (obviously with different query):

```
    FILE: index.php
    $result = myquery("SELECT itemName, mfrName, itemid,
              openingstock, conversion, reOrderQty FROM items ORDER BY itemName ASC;");
```

Before implementing this function program was fine, although applying this shorten my code by my page is very slow.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is stemming from opening a new connection every time you call a query! EEK! And it's never closed. You can either remove the "connect()" statement from your function, and make it a separate call. Or, for overall better code flow, switch to MySQLI OOP

I'd recommend moving to mysqli oop. It can be used like so

```
File: function.php
function getConnection() {
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
  return $mysqli;
}
```

And then utilize it in your other files like so

```
File: index.php
$mysql = getConnection();
$mysql->query("Select STUFF FROM PLACES");
//blah blah later in the file
$mysql->query("Another more different query!");
//end of file
$mysql->close();
```

See, here we reuse the same connection. Establishing MySQL connections over and over is a very expensive operation.